# React Native: What is the difference between running app with Xcode vs `react-native run-ios`?

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, xcodebuild

I know that clicking `run` in Xcode builds and runs the project. But running `react-native run-ios` also builds and runs it. What's the difference other than that Xcode has more specific error messages?

Answer (score 2):

```
react-native run-ios
```

is nothing but a CLI to help get you started with much more easier and faster ways to boot up the app. But for this command to execute you need to have Xcode installed and the build settings should be set to legacy so that it can be build and run properly.

The thing is suppose you want to run an app, opening the xcworkspace in your Xcode and then launching xcode , then indexing etc takes a lot of time.

SO thats where the CLI ,
 `react-native run-ios`
 helps to build faster. but at the end its the same build. This article will explain beautifully how it works. [rn-ios](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-run-a-react-native-app-on-ios-fc427be3c375/)

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts